# Visual Studio possible corrupted project - not recognizing most of the code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I have a big problem with a VS solution.  I was working on it a few months ago without any issues, then I left it dormant while working on other projects. Recently I opened it up again and found that it will not build and has errors in just about every file. It isn't recognizing the LINQ to SQL data context or most of the elements on the pages (web forms, by the way). It seems to be ignoring referenced projects and .dlls. A lot of things that are part of ASP.NET are also not recognized.

It's just a huge mess. Deleting all the temp files and the .suo file has not helped.  I tried creating a new .sln which also did not help.  I am not sure what to do at this point.  Any ideas?

Comment: Cannot say anything, unless you put .csproj or sln file in your question.

Comment: Do you try restoring nuget packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good solution to the problem, but I ended up manually changing files to make the application a 'website' instead of a web application. Fortunately it was a smaller scale site. I have no idea why that fixed it, but it did.